# MUI next Tooltip does not show on hover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I use Material-UIv1.0.0-beta.34 Tooltip with Checkbox and FormControlLabel, actually when I hover to the label on Checkbox in one case the tooltip shows as expected on another hand when I create a new one component(custom) with FormControlLabel and Checkbox inside it looks the tooltip does not work as expected.

https://codesandbox.io/s/n33p76n28p

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The `Tooltip` will work properly if you wrap the `Checkbox` in a `div` like so:

```
<Tooltip title="This tooltip works great">
  <div>
    <Checkbox label="This tooltip works on both text and checkbox." />
  </div>
</Tooltip>
<Tooltip title="This tooltip does not work">
  <Checkbox label="This tooltip does not work hovering on text, only hovering on checkbox." />
</Tooltip>
```

### The Cause

The `Tooltip` component works by responding to events on its children components (`onMouseEnter`, `onMouseLeave`, and a couple of others). It registers to those events by applying props to the top-level children.

When you wrap the `Checkbox` in a `div`, the `div` receives the `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` props and so the hover works properly.

However, when the you do not have a wrapping `div`, your custom `Checkbox` receives `onMouseOver` and `onMouseLeave` as part of its `props`. You take these `props` and spread them into the `MuiCheckbox` like so:

```
<FormControlLabel
  control={<MuiCheckbox {...props} />}
  label={label ? label : ""}
/>
```

So, you're effectively applying `onMouseOver` and `onMouseLeave` only to the `MUICheckbox` itself, and not to the label. So the hover only works on the `Checkbox` and not the label.

If you wanted, you could also fix this problem by spreading the props throughout the whole custom component:

```
export const Checkbox = ({ error, helperText, ...props }) => {
  // Capture all of the other props in other
  let { disabled, label, ...other } = props;
  let icon;

  if (disabled) icon = <Info color="disabled" />;
  else if (error) icon = <Warning color="error" />;

  // Spread the other props throughout the top-level div
  return (
    <div {...other}>
      <div>
        <FormControlLabel
          control={<MuiCheckbox {...props} />}
          label={label ? label : ""}
        />
        {!!helperText && (
          <FormHelperText error={error} disabled={disabled}>
            {!!icon && icon}
            {helperText}
          </FormHelperText>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I didn't suggest that solution originally because it can change the logic of your component if you're not careful, while a wrapping `div` should be pretty safe.

Comment: @PalaniichukDmytro I've expanded my answer to explain why a wrapping `div` fixes your problem.

Comment: thanks a lot, now it is more clear that tooltip populates its props down to the children

Comment: live saver @Jules Dupont

Comment: this messes up the placement of the tooltip

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is curious, this solution proposed by @JulesDupont also works for GatsbyImage:

```
<IconTooltip TransitionComponent={Fade} title={interest.text}>
                <div>
                  <GatsbyImage
                    image={interest.image.asset.gatsbyImageData}
                    alt={interest.alttext}
                  />
                </div>
              </IconTooltip>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the tooltip on top of a Dialog or Paper. The reason maybe from Z-index. Hope this is helpful for your debugging.